# Crash when calling init_node while holding GIL

Tags: python, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting a crash when trying to invoke rospy from within an embedded Python interpreter.

Ubuntu 14.04LTS
Python 2.7.6
rosdistro: jade
rosversion: 1.11.16

The following C/C++ file duplicates the problem:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Py_InitializeEx(0);
    PyEval_InitThreads();

    static const char *argv0 = "test";
    PySys_SetArgv(1, (char **) &argv0);

    PyEval_ReleaseLock();

    PyGILState_STATE gstate;
    gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

    PyRun_SimpleString("import rospy");
    printf ("import rospy - successful\n");

    PyRun_SimpleString("rospy.init_node('OpenCog_Eva')");
    PyGILState_Release(gstate);

    Py_Finalize();
    printf ("finished\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The crashes are of the form:

```
Fatal Python error: ceval: tstate mix-up
Aborted
```

or

```
Segmentation fault
```

or

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_SaveThread: NULL tstate
Aborted
```

or

```
Fatal Python error: GC object already tracked
Aborted
```

These are all problems that come about when the GIL locking isn't quite right.

Any ideas how to fix this crash?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227691/crash-when-calling-init_node-while-holding-gil/) by [inflector](https://answers.ros.org/users/26089/inflector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-02-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found it!! Use `PyEval_SaveThread()` instead of `PyEval_ReleaseLock()`.  Several websites clearly state that `PyEval_ReleaseLock()` is to be used, but it seems they're wrong.  The official python documentation has a cryptic warning that suggests that using  `PyEval_SaveThread()` is preferred.  And indeed, that fixes the bug!

---

Originally posted by [linas](https://answers.ros.org/users/26009/linas/) with karma: 26 on 2016-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inflector](https://answers.ros.org/users/26089/inflector/) on 2016-02-27**:
Interesting, I tried that in the sample and it still crashed.

I needed to do two additional things for the sample:

1. Put a `rospy.spin()` in somewhere before releasing the GIL.
2. Swap back in the main thread's state with `PyThreadState_Swap(thread_state)` before `Py_Finalize()`.